# Not able to copy text,XPath or other attribute from the chrome developer tool

Tags: google-chrome

I followed the approach mentioned in [how to emulate a mobile (android) browser on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212610/how-to-emulate-a-mobile-android-browser-on-desktop)

to project the mobile webpage's properties on desktop chrome browser. I was successfully able to do that  but now I have some queries as mentioned below, please let me know your inputs on that

a) How to use the "Select element option" of chrome developer toolbar to view an element's property for a mobile webpage. In normal desktop chrome browser we have the web page displayed and below that the developer toolbar is displayed and we can easily spot the element using a pointer but with mobile webpage displayed on desktop chrome browser i am not able to use this option as the webpage is not displayed.

b) I tried to copy the xpath and other things from the displayed HTML (HTML of mobile webpage on desktop chrome browser) but it gave me an error that "You need to install a Chrome extension that grants clipboard access to Developer tools". I installed one such extension named: "Auto Copy" but then also I was not able to copy. Please let me know how to go about it.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Namit

Comment: Hey Friends, Any inputs???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (B) – Judging from [the discussion when that message was introduced](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86621), it sounds like you need to roll your own simple custom extension to enable clipboard access.  Here's a [sample manifest.json](http://pastebin.com/kDxUacJd) – I haven't tested it out myself, but it looks pretty straightforward.  The [extension development Getting Started guide](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) explains how to turn a file like this into a working extension and install it locally.